# LinkingIOS.addEventListener for deep linking is not working when the app is closed

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking

When deep linking to the app when it is closed I can't get to _handleOpenURL(e) to be able to handle that url.

When the app is in the background deep linking is working fine.

Does anyone have some idea why is this happening and if it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is being launched from a deep link you have to handle that slightly different.

Basically while working through your boot up sequence you would call LinkingIOS.popInitialURL() and check it for a url. If there is one, handle it

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linkingios.html#content

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however that is the weird behaviour that I'm getting. If the app is opened in the background I can successfully open the link with LinkingIOS.popInitialURL('url', this._handleOpenURL) and handle it. But when the app is closed(not it the background) looks like I cannot get to this._handleOpenURL, for some reason the code inside it is not firing.